# Mod rewrite / clean urls problem

Tags: php, drupal

I've been using a drupal 4.7 installation for many years, and have had a recent problem crop up.  That is, the rewritten URLs are now displaying these characters: ?q= in every drupal generated URL as follows: http://sitename.com/?q=path/alias , where before it would be: http://sitename.com/path/alias .

My best guess as to why this might be happening, is that I recently began using some PHP code to add context-specific link styling within a few sideblocks.  Here's the code:

```
<?php   $alias= $_GET['q']; ?>

<a <?php $pos=strpos($alias,"1234"); // node number
if(!$pos == false) {
echo 'style="color:black"'; 
} ?> href="internal/link/alias">Internal Link</a>
```

Or more recently:

```
<?php $path = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '<front>';
$alias = url($path, array('absolute' => TRUE)); ?> 

<a <?php $pos=strpos($alias,"internal/link/alias"); 
if(!$pos == false) {
echo 'style="color:black"';
} ?> href="internal/link/alias">Internal Link</a>
```

Could this be the problem?  If so, any ideas about fixes?

Comment: If you comment that code out, does it stop doing it? That would be the best way to verify that it's causing it.

Comment: also, make sure you didn't munge your .htaccess. Your code doesn't look like it ought to add ?= to me.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, will try if nothing else comes up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your snippet is causing it. It only reads from the database; it does not make changes to URLs. Is mod_rewrite still enabled? This may be caused by a recent change to the server config. Check the output of `phpinfo()`.

By the way, the option `$absolute` for `url()` is [passed as a separate argument](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/url/4.7) in Drupal 4.7, not in the `$options` array. Your call should be:

```
url($path, $absolute=TRUE);
```

Comment: Thank you Ayman!  Helpful info.  Will check as best I can.  Unfortunately, my server access is quite limited, so my workarounds must be innovative...  long story.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that your clean urls are just broken.  When you don't have clean URLs turned on, all your URLs will look like `http://example.com/?q=/foo/bar/baz`.  The rewrite rules translate requests from `http://example.com/foo/bar/baz` **into** `http://example.com/?q=/foo/bar/baz` to be processed internally.

You need to go back and make sure that your rewrite rules still work (can you even go to `http://example.com/foo/bar/bazz` ?) and that Drupal has clean URLs turned on.

Comment: Yes, the rewrite rules still seem to be working, as http://example.com/foo/bar/bazz still works.  It's only the drupal generated URLs that add the extra characters ?q=

Answer (score 1):

Go into admin/settings and make sure Clean URLs is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Upload an unmodified .htaccess file to the root of the site again
2. Make sure your apache has mod_rewrite available. If you have shell access and it's an Ubuntu/Debian machine, just do

   a2enmod rewrite
3. Check if the option is enabled on admin/settings
4. Create a simple .php file on the root folder and type:

   phpinfo();

Then just see if the module is working.